# Password criteria 3 out of 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to write a password validator. The password has the following criteria.

1. At least 7 characters.
2. And should include 3 out of 4 of the following:

   - A number
   - A Upper Case
   - A lower Case
   - A special character (e.g., ! @ # )

The current regex:

```
/(^(?=.[^!@#$%^&*()'":;]{6,128}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).*)/
```

Is there any way to write the regex for meeting 3 out of 4 password requirements?

Comment: It's better if you write 4 separate tests

Comment: Better if you have no validation at all, just use min length. Forcing users to include various characters has been proven in some studies to lead to unsafe behavior like writing it down (virtually or physically) in an unsafe location. One new study out suggests not to attach any complexity requirements at all, just a min. length and that's it. Link to one such study: https://arstechnica.com/security/2013/06/password-complexity-rules-more-annoying-less-effective-than-length-ones/

Comment: @Igor really agree with you here

Comment: I agree with @JoeFrambach; it would be way easier to use separate tests and count how many pass. The only way of doing this with a single regex is pretty much test for every combination. It's possible to optimise to some degree, but would be way less efficient and tiresome to write and test.

Comment: @Igor I agree that these password restrictions do not improve security. Unfortunately that fact has not trickled down to some institutions and certifications (SOC 2). Organizations that need those certifications will be stuck with implementing those restrictions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all 4, you're looking for this:

```
/^(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])(?=.{7,})/
```

Multiple positive lookaheads for each of the conditions you listed.

If you want 3 out of the 4, you can write the permutations of three of the four, which gets really messy:

```
/^((?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])|(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])|(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])|(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z]))(?=.{7,})/
```

Run an example if you like:

```js
var regex = /^((?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])|(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])|(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*[^A-Za-z0-9\s])|(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z]))(.{7,})/
pw = document.getElementById("pw");
pw.oninput = function(e) {
  if (regex.test(e.target.value)) {
    pw.className = "valid";
  } else {
    pw.className = "invalid";
  }
};
```

```css
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
input {
  border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
  padding: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

input.invalid {
  border: 1px solid #c0392b;
}

input.valid {
  border: 1px solid #27ae60;
}
```

```html
<label>Type a password: <input id="pw" type="text"/></label>
```

If you want my opinion, these are really frustrating for the user. I'd just put a minimum length of 8 characters and leave password security to them.